# Refactoring existing code with some design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have the following code, like a git command line system with various supported parameters and commands. But as can be seen, it involves a lot of if-else conditions which
It doesn't seem that clean and is error-prone. Could there be a way to restructure it using some design pattern

```
public static void main(String... args) {
            String firstParam;
            try {
                firstParam = args[0];
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a command.");
                return;
            }
            String secondParam = null; String thirdParam = null; String fourthParam = null;
            if (args.length > 1) {
                secondParam = args[1];
            }
            if (args.length > 2) {
                thirdParam = args[2];
            }
            if (args.length > 3) {
                fourthParam = args[3];
            }
            git git = new git();
            if (firstParam.equals("init")) {
                git.init();
            } else if (!git.getWorkingdirectory().exists()) {
                System.out.println("not initialized");
            } else if (firstParam.equals("status")) {
                git.status();
            } else if (firstParam.equals("log")) {
                git.log();
            } else if (firstParam.equals("global-log")) {
                git.globalLog();
            }
            else if (secondParam == null) {
                System.out.println("Incorreerands.");
            } else if (firstParam.equals("add")) {
                git.add(secondParam);
            } else if (firstParam.equals("rm")) {
```

**Reasoning:** 
The first thing that comes to my mind is making a class out of each command. That's probably called command pattern. So there will be a class corresponding to - add, rm, status, log, etc.. all the supported arguments to the git command. I am planning to include around 13 such git commands to be specified as a command-line option. That will be like 13 classes.
Not sure if that is a good approach, or could there be any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely go with a class for each command that you support. You would not only have a better-organized codebase, but it would be easier to test, maintain and extend if you need to add support for additional commands.
Don't be afraid of having many classes if that is what makes sense to your use case. I would be more afraid of having too few classes that would turn your code unmanageable and unreadable.